# finding the percentage using case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

The following SQL Query :

```
SELECT 

SUM(aol_int) AS AOL,
SUM(android_phone_int) AS Android_Phone,
SUM(androidTablet_int) AS Android_Tablet

FROM mytable;
```

Is giving me the total values under AOL, Android_Phone and Android_Tablet columns

However, I am trying to get the percentage of AOL, Android_Phone and Android_Tablet and hence I decided to write the above query as follows:

```
SELECT 

SUM(CASE WHEN 'aol_int' THEN 100 END) / Count(aol_int) AS AOL,
SUM(CASE WHEN ‘android_phone_int’ THEN 100 END) /Count(android_phone_int) AS Android_Phone,
SUM(CASE WHEN ‘androidTablet_int’ THEN 100 END)/Count(androidTablet_int) AS Android_Tablet

FROM mytable;
```

And I am getting NULL in each column. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should load sqlfiddle.com with sample data and show what you expect the output to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those 3 add up to 100 percent, then you can sumply divide each sum by the total sum to get the percentages. I get the idea that you want to see 20% as "20.00" as opposed to "0.2", so in my example I'll multiple the ration by 100 and round it off at a decimal precision of 2, but it's easy for you to change those as you see fit.

```
select 
round((sum(aol_int) /
  (sum(aol_int + android_phone_int + androidtablet_int))) *
  100,2) as aol_percentage,
round((sum(android_phone_int) /
  (sum(aol_int + android_phone_int + androidtablet_int))) * 
  100,2) as android_phone_percentage,
round((sum(androidtablet_int) /
  (sum(aol_int + android_phone_int + androidtablet_int))) * 
  100,2) as android_tablet_percentage
from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks @Ike Walker. This is what I was looking for. I was kind of looking it to fit with CASE statement but nevertheless, your answer works perfectly fine.

Comment: Actually @Ike Walker , I have around 20 columns for which I am calculating the percentage. When I used for 3, the three percentages were summing up to 100 , however, for 20 columns, my all percentage values are summing up to 426.